# SDK Manager will not work

Tags: xcopy, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am running windows 7 64 bit and I can't run my sdk manager. I've tried command prompt. I've done alot of RandD and can't seem to get it too work. I mean i don't get it. If Microsoft wants us to spend more money on their 64 bit operating systems why would they make it less functional than their 32 bit operating system? Anyways, here is there error I get every time try to run my sdk manager:

```
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Access is denied.
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3550 or swt-win32 in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:334)
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:308)
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:119)
[2013-06-19 23:39:29 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. Just had to right click sdk manager and run it as an administrator.